# MS SQL Server completing procedure but not updating table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that executes without error but doesn't add anything into the table. I've tried dropping and recreating the table. I've compared the procedure line by line to a different very similar procedure for a different table which works and I didn't find any differences.

Here is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPostMedia_Create]

@PostID int,
@ImageName varchar(64),
@VideoName varchar(64)

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO PostMedias ([PostID], [ImageName], [VideoName], [CreatedDateTime])
    VALUES (@PostID, @ImageName, @VideoName, GETDATE())

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [PostMedia_PostMediaID]

END
GO
```

Here is my query:

```
DECLARE @return_value int


EXEC @return_value =
    dbo.spPostMedia_Create
        @PostID = 6,
        @ImageName = 'CDD4A0CB9DEA4F739E76239F0143EA85.jpg',
        @VideoName = 'NULL'

SELECT
    'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Here is the result of the above query:

```
PostMedia_PostMediaID = NULL
Return Value = -6
```

What am I missing?

Edit: This is the code I use to generate the table:

```
CREATE TABLE PostMedias(
    PostMediaID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    PostID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Posts(PostID),
    ImageName varchar(64),
    VideoName varchar(64),
    CreatedDateTime datetime NOT NULL
)
```

HOWEVER, using sp_help reveals `No identity column defined.` Am I forgetting something?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with scope_identity() here? - if postid is not an identity value this wont work - scope identity returns the last identity value inserted into the table

Comment: Why are you passing a string literal of NULL? If there is nothing you should pass NULL, not a string. And what do you mean nothing gets inserted? It will either insert a row or raise an exception. Can you share the table definition?

Comment: @DanielMarcus There's another column in `PostMedias` called PostMediaID` which is the primary key for `PostMedias`. I'm using SCOPE_IDENTITY() to get that newly inserted `PostMediaID` back to me.

Comment: @SeanLange That was automatically generated, I didn't notice. Changed it to `NULL` with no difference.

Comment: And you are not returning anything so checking @return_value is pointless.

Comment: Ok I see - try creating a variable then selecting scope identity = the variable and selecting that

Comment: @SeanLange The query is just to check the procedure, nothing else. I just need the procedure to insert into the table. I understand that it might be pointless but it shouldn't be interfering with the execution of the procedure.

Comment: So check the table. Do that with a select statement. Like I said previously it is either inserting a row or raising an exception. An insert statement that is not in a try/catch is not going to just not insert something.

Comment: @DanielMarcus the scope identity problem is secondary right now. I'm trying to figure out why nothing is inserted into the table.

Comment: Please provide the table definition for `PostMedias`. I ran your code as is on a test database and it inserts everytime.

Comment: @SeanLange I agree it shouldn't just insert something and I've checked the table by SELECTs but nothing is inserted.

Comment: That is impossible. Plain and simple what you are describing is NOT happening. Please post the table definition. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Are there triggers on the table? Maybe that is preventing the insert?

Comment: @SQLChao Please see the update.

Comment: @SeanLange Please see the update.

Comment: You don't have an identity on your table. Of course SCOPE_IDENTITY is not going to have the value you expect.

Comment: When I have this kind of problem I usually find my code is running on one database / server and the query window I’m using to check is on a different database / server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't supplying a value for PostMediaID which is `not null`. You should have gotten the error

```
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PostMediaID', table 'dbo.PostMedias'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

Maybe add identity property.

```
CREATE TABLE PostMedias(
    PostMediaID int NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    PostID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Posts(PostID),
    ImageName varchar(64),
    VideoName varchar(64),
    CreatedDateTime datetime NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: The return code -6 indicated an error with severity -16 was raised. The client app should have been detected the error and displayed the message.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take some wild guesses.

1. It it possible you have TWO (yes two) tables named `PostMedias`. One table is in your user's default schema, while the second is in `dbo`. Your procedure is updating the one in your default schema, but not the one in `dbo`.
2. You are running this as part of a transaction. Unfortunately, you're not committing the transaction before breaking the connection, which causes your change to rollback.

Couldn't help but notice you're checking for a return code, but you're not actually returning anything in the sproc. Try something like...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.deezNuts
 AS
 DECLARE @something tinyint = 1
 RETURN(@something)
GO
DECLARE @thing tinyint;
EXECUTE @thing = dbo.deezNuts;
PRINT @thing;
GO
```

Here is the test code I was using for anyone else troubleshooting this...

```
use tempdb
GO
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.PostMedias
GO
create table dbo.PostMedias (
    id int identity(1,1)
  , PostID int 
  , ImageName varchar(max)
  , VideoName varchar(max)
  , CreatedDateTime datetime2 default (getdate())
)
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPostMedia_Create]
@PostID int,
@ImageName varchar(64),
@VideoName varchar(64)
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PostMedias ([PostID], [ImageName], [VideoName], [CreatedDateTime])
    VALUES (@PostID, @ImageName, @VideoName, GETDATE())

    SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [PostMedia_PostMediaID]
END
GO
DECLARE @return_value int
EXEC @return_value =
    dbo.spPostMedia_Create
        @PostID = 6,
        @ImageName = 'CDD4A0CB9DEA4F739E76239F0143EA85.jpg',
        @VideoName = 'NULL'
SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

After noticing that there was no identity on the table. I changed my table definition to this:

```
CREATE TABLE PostMedias(
    PostMediaID int NOT IDENTITY(1,1)  NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    PostID int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Posts(PostID),
    ImageName varchar(64),
    VideoName varchar(64),
    CreatedDateTime datetime NOT NULL
)
```

For some reason, I haven't had to use `IDENTITY(1,1)` before so I wasn't thinking that was a problem.

Answer (score 0):

try the below
  ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spPostMedia_Create]

```
@PostID int,
@ImageName varchar(64),
@VideoName varchar(64)

AS

SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @[PostMedia_PostMediaID] INT

BEGIN

    INSERT INTO PostMedias ([PostID], [ImageName], [VideoName], (CreatedDateTime])
    VALUES (@PostID, @ImageName, @VideoName, GETDATE())

    SELECT @[PostMedia_PostMediaID] = CONVERT (INT,SCOPE_IDENTITY())

    SELECT @[PostMedia_PostMediaID] AS 'Scope Identity'

    RETURN

END
GO
```